# Proper way to check a property of Mongoose Document is empty

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Suppose a schema

```js
const sch = new mongoose.Schema({
  obj: {
    subObj: String;
  }
});
```

Then I observe that an non-existing or empty property of a document gives me `isEmpty == false`.

```js
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
// Insert an empty document (i.e. no `obj` property)
Sch.create([{}]);

Sch.findOne({}. (err, doc) => {
  // Below gives `{}`
  console.log(doc.obj);
  // Below gives `false`
  console.log(`isEmpty == ${isEmpty(doc.obj)`);
});
```

I suspect that it is because the document contains `obj` as its key, i.e. `Object.keys(doc).includes('obj') == true` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(doc).includes('obj') == true`. But I have no idea to deal with it.

What is a proper way to check emptiness of a mongoose document property ?

Comment: can you print doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in mongoose itself. The below does what I tried with lodash

```
doc.$isEmpty('obj')
```

**Reference**

1. [Document.prototype.$isEmpty()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-$isEmpty)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

The reason that you are getting that is:

```js
console.log(Object.keys(doc.obj), Object.keys({}));
```

when running the command above I get: `[ '$init', 'subObj' ] []` which means that your `Object` is not really empty, `lodash` is probably checking those attributes

You could use something like this:

```js
Sch.findOne({}, (err, doc) => {
  if (JSON.stringify(doc.obj) === JSON.stringify({}) ) {
     // logic goes here
  }
});
```

Comment: Read question twice